# About patterns with typed data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a difficulty to define the pattern to obtain this result:

```
Function[TypedData[{{1,2}, 2, {2,3,4}}] = True 

Function[TypedData[{{1,2}, 2, {2,3,4}}], TypedData[{{a, 1}, d, 1}]]= True
```

Here what I m trying :

```
Function[TypedData[{_list,_,_list}]__] := True
```

I put a BlankSequence after my TypedData because I wanted my function answers True if I have 1 or several TypedData but I doesn’t work.

May you help me to define a good pattern which can work with the TypedData ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it with `List` instead of `list`? Also you probably want `..` at the end of the pattern instead of `__`. And the blank in the middle insists on a middle expression, so three expressions inside `TypedData`, with lists at the beginning and end.  Is that what you want?

Comment: i think you are completely right about the .. but i need also a blanksequence to ask Mathematica that i can have 1 or several typed Data. Indeed, Typed data is composed of list of 3 expressions

Comment: @Michael E2 OK. it woks but i didn't understand why ".." can replace "__". How i have been able to do if have wanted 0, 1 or several typed Data in my case ?

Comment: `Function[TypedData[{_List, _, _List}]..] := True` may be the answer. It seems to be a mistake that in your original expression there is only a left brace. It's a syntax error.

Comment: @MichaelE2 a remind so that you can see my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: First, as helpful technique, learn to use `FullForm` (and perhaps to assume that your understanding is wrong somehow -- that's usually the explanation for why something doesn't work the I thought it would): `FullForm[TypedData[{_list, _, _list}] __]` (read the output carefully). What would match the pattern you see? Would this match it?: `MatchQ[TypedData[{list[1, 3], "Yoicks!", list[5, 6, 7, 8]}] 2 x, TypedData[{_list, _, _list}] __]`. Then go through the docs for `Repeated` and `RepeatedNull` and their examples, and see if you can replace them by `BlankSequence` or `BlankNullSequence`.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Note that it is generally not a good idea to begin user-defined symbols with a capital letter since this could give rise to naming conflicts with built-in names. Perhaps what you intend is

```
typedDataQ[{_List, _Integer, _List} ..] := True
```

Note that if the middle argument is not intended to be an [`Integer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html) just use `_` or perhaps some other [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) such as [`Real`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html) or [`Rational`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational.html) or [`String`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html)

Then to handle all other arguments

```
typedDataQ[___] := False
```

Testing valid data

```
typedDataQ[{{1, 2}, 2, {2, 3, 4}}]

(* True *)
```

Testing invalid data

```
typedDataQ[{3, 2, {2, 3, 4}}]

(* False *)
```

Testing multiple valid data

```
typedDataQ[{{1, 2}, 2, {2, 3, 4}}, {{6, 9, 6, 8}, 2, {1, 8, 2}}]

(* True *)
```

Testing mix of valid and invalid data

```
typedDataQ[{{1, 2}, 2, {2, 3, 4}}, {{6, 9, 6, 8}, 2, 7}]

(* False *)
```

Testing mix, item-by-item

```
typedDataQ /@ {{{1, 2}, 2, {2, 3, 4}}, {{6, 9, 6, 8}, 2, 7}}

(* {True, False} *)
```

Comment: Thank you ! You perfectly answer to my question

Comment: Note also that `_List` covers a wide variety of structures. Depending on the application, you might want a tighter restriction such as `_?VectorQ`

Comment: in fact it was not what I expected. I answered to quickly. I wanted the repeated .. after the TypedData and that is to say after the closing bracket

Comment: may you have a look at my comment ?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense to me. Don't tell us how to code, tell us how you want the code to perform. Provide examples of input for which the provided code does not do as you expect and tell us the result that you want instead. I will be away from my computer for 8 or 9 hours.